# Multiprocessing process does not run

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have been trying to run a very simple multiprocessing program (script below). However, the output I am getting is simply: `"Finished"`. Neither process or function  produces any output. How do I ensure that they actually do run and I get an output that looks something like `"Function 1" "Function 2" "Finished"`?

Apologies if this is a duplicate question and any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import multiprocessing

def func(n):
    print('Function',n)

p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=func, args=(1, ))
p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=func, args=(2, ))

p1.start()
p2.start()

p1.join()
p2.join()

print("Finished")
```

Computer info: Python version 3.8.8, macOS 12.0.1, Apple M1 chip

Comment: Depending on the OS you do not receive the stdout output of a subprocess on your console.

Comment: Multiprocessing starts new processes, are you sure it's not running and just outputting to stdout that goes to nowhere? Did you try for example creating a file in the process instead of just printing something?

Comment: Ah yes thank you! Sending the output to a file works. Is there a way to make it actually print to the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `__name__ == '__main__'` to your code to make sure that the main module can be safely imported by a new Python interpreter without causing unintended side effects.

```
def func(n):
    print('Function',n)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=func, args=(1, ))
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=func, args=(2, ))
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    print("Finished")
```

source: [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-programming)

Comment: Tried that too and got the same result.

Comment: That is strange, it worked for me on my M1 chip, but with python 3.9.2. Also worked in python 2.7

Comment: Okay I'll try updating to Python 3.9 then. Maybe that'll work